# How to setup Gearman to execute a application on one particular server?

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, gearman

Here is my situation:

I have multiple servers under a load balancer. My users are able to upload files to the server. These files need to modify and sent to another server. So to do that I decided to use Gearman to manage queues of the PHP scripts that will do the work.

Here is the problem. What happens if one server goes down... Then gearman executes the code to get a particular file but that file was on the server that went down. How can I setup gearman to wait for the server that went down to finally get the right file... Also it might happen that the servers might not go down but since gearman talks to the other servers it might execute the code on another machine looking for a file that is on another server.

How can I get around this problem?  Without having to isolate each gearman servers from each other. Because I will use it for other things that don't have the same restrains.